# Unwanted Extent Remains when Clipping and Merging in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip, merge

I have 4 adjacent rasters with a 2-pixel gap between each other. 2 of the rasters have unwanted extents that bleed into the 2-pixel gap:

[image: Unwanted Extent Circled in Red]

I have clipped out the unwanted extents from the 2 rasters using Raster > Extraction > Clip Raster By Extent and saved the clipped rasters as new files:

[image: Unwanted Extent Clipped Out]

However, when merging the updated rasters using Raster > Miscellaneous > Merge, the unwanted extents reappear in the output raster:

[image: Unwanted Extents Reappeared]

I have tested with the Identify Features tool and the unwanted extents are of the same elevation as in the original rasters, meaning the extents were not actually removed but visually hidden. How should I go about permanently removing the extents before merging?

Comment: I have solved the issue. The problem was that the rasters' CRS and Extent coordinates were not set in their Metadata. I have regenerated the values for each raster. The merged tool now produces the intended raster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. The problem was that the 4 rasters' CRS and Extent coordinates were not set in their Metadata. I have regenerated the values for each raster. The Merge tool now produces the intended raster.